# $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=f(x)$ with boundary conditions, how to find integration bounds

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, upper-lower-bounds

Given $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=f(x),\quad y(-1)=y(1)=0,$$ I used $u=y'$ and $u(x_0)=u_0$ to get
$$
u(x)=u_0+\int_{x_0}^xf(\xi)d\xi.
$$

Then we have $y'=u$, which we can integrate again using $y(x_0)=y_0$ to get

$$
y(x)=y_0+\int_{x_0}^x\Big(u_0+\int_{x_0}^\zeta f(\xi)d\xi\Big)d\zeta=(y_0-u_0x_0)+u_0x+\int_{x_0}^x\Big(\int_{x_0}^\zeta f(\xi)d\xi\Big)d\zeta.
$$

**Now my question is**, what do I do with $y_0,x_0$ and $u_0$ to get it into the normal form using $C_1,C_2$? [Wolfram Alpha gives the following expression](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27(x)%3Df(x)):

$$
y(x)=C_1+C_2x+\int_{1}^x\Big(\int_{1}^\zeta f(\xi)d\xi\Big)d\zeta,
$$

but how did they set $x_0=1$? Because we didn't use any boundary conditions yet. I understand $C_1$ and $C_2$ as just relabeling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because
$$\int_{x_0}^x f(t) dt=\int_1^x f(t) dt - \int_1^{x_0} f(t) dt=\int_1^x f(t) dt - k$$
For some $k\in\mathbb{R}$. Hence
$$\int_{x_0}^x\Big(\int_{x_0}^\zeta f(\xi)d\xi\Big)d\zeta=\int_{x_0}^x\Big(\int_1^\zeta f(\xi)d\xi-k_1\Big)d\zeta$$
$$=\int_1^x\Big(\int_1^\zeta f(\xi)d\xi-k_1\Big)d\zeta-k_2$$
$$=\int_1^x\Big(\int_1^\zeta f(\xi)d\xi\Big)d\zeta-\int_1^xk_1d\zeta-k_2$$
$$=\int_1^x\Big(\int_1^\zeta f(\xi)d\xi\Big)d\zeta-k_1(x-1)-k_2$$
$$=\int_1^x\Big(\int_1^\zeta f(\xi)d\xi\Big)d\zeta+k_3x+k_4$$
So
$$y(x)=y_0-u_0x_0+u_0x+\int_1^x\Big(\int_1^\zeta f(\xi)d\xi\Big)d\zeta+k_3x+k_4$$
$$=C_1+C_2x+\int_1^x\Big(\int_1^\zeta f(\xi)d\xi\Big)d\zeta$$

Comment: But the expression I found has integration bounds from $x_0$ to $x$, so that isn't a constant right?

Comment: Yes the upper bound is variable, but as long as one of the bounds is constant, it can take any chosen value because the change in value only effects the result by a constant amount. This amount can be corrected by subtracting some constant which is written as part of $C_1$

Comment: So we can set $x_0=1$ because we just subtract another integral with some other bound to correct for this? How did you get the integral in your answer?

Comment: Is that enough of an explanation for you now?